# how to delete a row in the database while using hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have created a classes  as below

```
public class User {
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
private List<Address> userAddresses;
....
....
}

public class userAddress {
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
private User usr;
.....
....
}
```

If I delete a single row in the User table will it automatically delete the row in userAddress. If not please let me know the way to declare the property to delete automatically. I heard about cascade thing but I do not know the right syntax to declare it.

Comment: Look up the `orhpanRemoval` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping it like this:

```
public class User {
      @OneToMany(mappedBy="usr", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval="true")
      private List<Address> userAddresses;
}            

public class userAddress {
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="ID")
      private User usr;
}
```

Comment: I am able to delete User records if I delete UserAddress record first. Otherwise it is not allowing to delete the record directly in User table.

Comment: So what is it you want to do? You want the userAdresses to be deleted upon deletion of the user record?

Comment: Yes, I want userAdresses to be deleted upon deletion of the user record.